# DKIM to gmail failing

Tags: linux, email, exim, dkim

I'm trying to get DKIM setup on a CentOS 7 server running exim but gmail is returning

```
dkim=neutral (bad format) header.i=@ellie-oli.com;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=ellie-oli.com; s=mail;
h=; bh=VAgC5MVP54VmvlcGQaMT2ZdmokXkhMKi/RNSpcUu2qw=;
b=agz8IPjjK9+CerCMv5EDEl3DCVuakvU6StLQUgLTrnmVPPyazb0/Moi5pAopJdGJEUaHNhf9V2dFQNrcDUDw7AxqCUKT+pXwHDPq1tGIhtyntRy4LcoIBaEAf6eieVNScPQHX/hj2AUdMEVk1DaNwnh5rZbNGCydaMbVQFwbLLEXJbaY0sDt8Zpi/BF1JArxUMUeuJZlFGgU8LBpuQ671xuNVxMoK0Bfak3YEJjCx6LWhZBQLRKs2scZ/BHuDKLziY6n7GML8dPcgCpwo/wODJYXnDHxDY7MNCnEF6b110uQKje4kkQG32gVjJHr/gpeinQOWJ/oZAicJcnIp7kH8g==;
```

my exim config looks like

```
remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp_dkim for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
  hosts_avoid_tls = REMOTE_SMTP_HOSTS_AVOID_TLS
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
  headers_rewrite = REMOTE_SMTP_HEADERS_REWRITE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
  return_path = REMOTE_SMTP_RETURN_PATH
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
  helo_data=REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA
.endif
dkim_domain = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch*@{/etc/exim/dkim_senders}}
dkim_selector = mail
dkim_private_key = /etc/exim/dkim/mail.pem
dkim_canon = relaxed
dkim_strict = false
dkim_sign_headers = DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
```

The DNS record appears to work as far as I can tell and returns as

```
mail._domainkey.ellie-oli.com   text = "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzo9rv2QgABArrAwPgeR++q3Y/0HGWqoETE3N7/o3hwYBMpujcPM22Lp0PoMYStu/VyyZikM23nEnmlpeOiS8GdGL0ZbP5HatDqvZKoiu5mx5PODtea8XWoKsH1BV2ngOWt0d43SRMSCBT5vJ9tJpjYe20B3lE2XEXHbrxZ5vWajvAi3vFFJ4mQSUKisQ+KV+NEt" "pqR9bm9KTk0HbeykdSwjvsz78eHCbJQUI+C9sn5MrKmdatqHOHA1fjf6iqbc7kdA08MGr3KoiySAFrPqRLR/Pw1oRueU8ImPIzY3n2ZvZqMl2zTDhe/luxf6ecCEj0AbfwbGghRxMq4QIZDvzFwIDAQAB"
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the problems?

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd field of your DKIM record start with p= ?

Comment: You are correct, I have fixed it but unfortunately am still seeing problems, different DKIM-Signature now though.  I will edit the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signed header fields (the h-tag) in the DKIM signature is empty. According to the [RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#page-21) it must however contain at least one header name. The recommended header fields to sign are described in [section 5.4 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-5.4).

Probably the `DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS` variable contains something invalid.
`dkim_sign_headers` according to the [Exim specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-support_for_dkim_domainkeys_identified_mail.html):

> OPTIONAL: When set, this option must expand to (or be specified as) a
> colon-separated list of header names. Headers with these names will be
> included in the message signature. When unspecified, the header names
> recommended in RFC4871 will be used.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I shouldn't have had the below enabled as well as a mis configuration in the DNS record pointed out by eranga

```
dkim_sign_headers = DKIM_SIGN_HEADERS
```